# Impact of between-group differences in the independent variable on between-group differences in the dependent variable in a known model situation

Tags: t-test, interaction, modeling, continuous-data

I'm grappling with a specific question:

I have two independent groups and a known function  f = x ⋅ y ⋅ a + z, where  x, y, and z are variables and a is a constant (the same for every participant in both groups). All variables are numerical and continuous. I've obtained the values of x, y and z for each participant and computed the values of f using this equation.

My primary objective is to analyze the impact of differences in x,  y and z between the groups on the between-groups difference in f.

So far, I have tested for between-group differences in an independent variables and dependent variable. Next, I used the observed between-group differences in means of independent variables to calculate shifts in the dependent variable using the given equation (specifically I expressed "shift" as a ratio of f'/f'' where f'' is f value calculated using above equation with x, y, z values set to a mean of group "A" and f' is f value calculated using above equation with x value set to a mean of group "A" + between-group difference in means of x, y and z set to a mean of group "A" [and the same for y and z, separately, to isolate contribution of each variable]). I have also applied a lower and upper values of 95% confidence interval (CI) for differences in means to estimate what I might call a 95% CI for the contributions. However, I'm wondering if there is a better way to do this.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to CV.  Your question doesn't seem to be about statistics, because it appears only to ask how to compute the derivatives of $f$ with respect to $x,$ $y,$ and $z.$  If that's not your intent, could you please elaborate on what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: I believe that my question is strictly related to statistics. I think that misunderstandings arose from the unfortunate use of abbreviations in my original question. By dx, dy, dz, and df, I meant the between-group differences in variables x, y, z, and f, respectively. My question concerns how to test the statistical significance of the influence of between-group differences in an independent variable on between-group differences in a dependent variable, given a known relationship described by a specific equation.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.  Because it matters for the answers, please include some information about the nature of these variables (binary? categorical? numerical?).  It can help to describe the variables, particularly because a model this specialized is unusual and can be difficult to justify and interpret.

Comment: Thank you. I added further clarifications. All variables are numerical and continuous.